# How to Convert String Array into Prisma Select Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-deployment, prisma

I want to select Prisma columns dynamically, I am getting this from the client:

```
['id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'Order.id', 'Order.Item.id', 'Order.Item.desc']
```

I want to change it to something like this:

```
{id: true, createdAt: true, updatedAt: true, Order: {select: {id: true, Item: {select: {id: true, desc: true}}}}
```

so that I can use it in the Prisma query like:

```
prisma.sales.findMany({where: {id: {_eq: 1}}, select: {id: true, createdAt: true, updatedAt: true, Order: {select: {id: true, Item: {select: {id: true, desc: true}}}}}})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it works only for two-level

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70389807/edit) your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a simple recursive function to build object and populate the nested properties:

```js
const objPaths = ['id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'Order.id', 'Order.Item.id', 'Order.Item.desc'];


function buildObject(paths) {
    const result = {};
    for (const path of paths) {
        const pathParts = path.split(".");
        if (pathParts.length > 1) {
            populateNested(result, pathParts, 0);
        } else {
            result[path] = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function populateNested(parent, paths, currPathIndex) {
    if (currPathIndex === paths.length - 1) {
        parent[paths[currPathIndex]] = true;
    } else {
        let currObj = {select: {}};
        if (parent[paths[currPathIndex]]) {
            currObj = parent[paths[currPathIndex]];
        }
        parent[paths[currPathIndex]] = currObj;
        populateNested(currObj.select, paths, currPathIndex + 1);
    }

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(buildObject(objPaths), null, 2));
```